# Example of ClassName.method1Name().method2Name();

Tags: java

Hi any one give me example of ClassName.method1Name().method2Name() what is this please give me simple java program example of this.I am confusing of this code.

Comment: You mean something like `str.toUpperCase().replace("foo","bar");` from the `String` class?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: @MathewsMathai I see this in android sdk Toast.makeText().show() library   something like this .....Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: That's exactly the example I demonstrated... Although you're right, the first class's method should have been static. It's a chain of method calls on successive objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassName.get1().get2().get3()` is just a chain of method calls on successive classes. Imagine 3 objects:

```
class ClassName {
  public static o1 get1() {
    return new o1();    
  }
}
class o1 {
  public o2 get2() {
    return new o2();    
  }
}
class o2 {
  public o3 method3() {
    return new o3();
  }
}
```

In each instance, the function call returned another object, which itself had a method to call, and so on and so forth.

Comment: why you not declare static all the  methods ???? without static methods does this run ???

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't matter for the example. The reason I didn't declare them static is that later we may want to add state to the constructor.

Comment: How is static related to constructor?

Comment: If it's static, the constructor can't have state that mutates without causing a potential bugs due to globally storing 1 variable.

Comment: You can declare methods as static. Constructor has nothing to do with methods.

Comment: Why are you so obsessed with making these all static? It doesn't matter towards this example. Do you really think OP was wondering how static methods work? The reason I didn't make them static is because I didn't want to type static for education purposes.

Comment: @MathewsMathai http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_nonaccess_modifiers.htm read this carefully

Comment: @hansod1: your patience and composedness in the face of both the question and the comments is really inspiring. +1.

Comment: @hansod1 +1 So Sorry. I misunderstood. I realize that you are returning an object every time and so static is not required. Sorry once again.

Answer (score 0):

Return current object reference from method call using `return this;`

```
public class ReturnClassType {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    public ReturnClassType firstName(String firstname){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        return this;
    }

    public ReturnClassType lastName(String lastname){
        this.lastname = lastname;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return firstname + " " + lastname;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Name = new ReturnClassType().firstName("Vicky").lastName("Thakor").getName();
        System.out.println(Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanantion about the mechanism?

Comment: I can not want to create object ,,, I want to refer this using class name that is ReturnClassType().firstName("Vicky").lastName("Thakor").getName(); and Can I use static in all the methods ???

Comment: make the mathods static.

Comment: @MathewsMathai You can't refer `this` in `static` method.

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanRafique You've to stick to the `new ReturnClassType().firstName("Vicky").lastName("Thakor")` because `this` is not allowed in `static` method.

Comment: What if we `return new ReturnClassType()` instead of `return this` . Will that work?

Comment: `firstname` and `lastname` are static variable so object created using `return new ReturnClassType()` doesn't make any sense because they are never gonna be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Employee{
   public Static List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();
   private String name;
   Employee(){
   public Employee(){
       name = "";
   } 
   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name){
       this.name=name;
   }


}
public static void main(String [] args){
  Employee e = new Employee();
  e.setname("test");
  Employee e2 = new Employee();
  e2.setname("test2");
  Employee.list.add(e);
  Employee.list.add(e2);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < Employee.list.size(); i++){
     System.out.println(Employee.list.get(i).getName());
  }
}
```